# httpRequest temporarily freezes my application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oauth, httprequest

Okay, before I go on, let me state that my background is in web scripting; so applications are very foreign to me. I know very little about .NET and I've been skating by on my limited knowledge.

Anyways, in my application, I have an OAuth httpRequest. The request itself works fine, it gets the data I need from the web API. However, the problem is that whenever I click the button that activates the request, my program freezes for a few seconds until the request is finished. I also have another request which is done automatically every 60 seconds. Which of course means every 60 seconds, my program freezes for a few seconds. How to fix this?

```
    private string twitchCallAPI(string accessKey, string accessSecret, string endpointURI, string httpMethod)
    {
        OAuthHttpWebRequest httpRequest = new OAuthHttpWebRequest();
        httpRequest.ConsumerToken = new OAuthToken { Token = this.twitchConKey, TokenSecret = this.twitchConSecret };
        httpRequest.Token = new OAuthToken() { Token = accessKey, TokenSecret = accessSecret };
        httpRequest.SetUri(endpointURI);
        httpRequest.Method = httpMethod;

        try
        {
            using (var response = httpRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Note : this is only for the ' I also have another request which is done automatically every 60 seconds.' part.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this method working... even with the on click part. I just had the click method activate the worker.

Answer (score 2):

Shortly said, do request in task and update UI thread with UI synchronization context

```
TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>
{
    //do web request
})
.ContinueWith(() =>
{
    this.TextBlock1.Text = "Complete"; 
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Async methods, that is, using a different thread to wait for the response of the request. Its a solution that you can explore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I updated my first post with my code... could you go more in depth with how I make my code asynchronous?

Comment: what version of .Net are you targeting/using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use await keyword:

```
private async void OnButtonClick()
{
   TextBox.Text = await twitchCallAPIAsync(accessKey, accessSecret, endpointURI, httpMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of this is because your application is waiting the methods you launch to finish. You have to take a look at the 'async' concept.

A program executing an 'async' method continue its workflow, and doesn't wait the method to produce a result.

Comment: Hmm, I updated my first post with my code... could you go more in depth with how I make my code asynchronous?

Comment: I'm not considering myself experienced enough to teach you this concept. And it's not the place to do it. The only advice I can give you is you need to read some materials about 'async' concept. You should start on MSDN with IAsyncResult.